# Is it possible to apply a vertical gradient as well as a horizontal gradient fade-out on the sides of a graph?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to apply a vertical gradient as well as a horizontal gradient fade-out on the sides of a graph?

Here is an image that demonstrates what I am talking about. You can see that the graph in the back has a vertical CPTGradient fill for areaFill.

[image]

The code for that would roughly be like this:

```
CPTGradient *areaGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5f] endingColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.1f]];
areaGradient.angle = -90.0;
CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient];
tempPlot.areaFill = areaGradientFill;
tempPlot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
```

For the edges of the graph, I would do something like this:

```
CPTGradient *gradient2 = [[CPTGradient alloc] init];
gradient2 = [gradient2 addColorStop:[CPTColor clearColor] atPosition:0.0];
gradient2 = [gradient2 addColorStop:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5f] atPosition:.05];
gradient2 = [gradient2 addColorStop:[CPTColor clearColor] atPosition:.05];
gradient2 = [gradient2 addColorStop:[CPTColor clearColor] atPosition:1.];
gradient2.angle = 180.f;
tempPlot.areaFill2 = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient2];
tempPlot.areaBaseValue2 = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
```

However, the problem is that this doesn't play nicely with the other gradient:
[image]

How can I achieve a 'fade out' effect on each side of the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer. For the fade on the edges of the graph, I use a CAGradientLayer mask on the host view, where `self.hostView` is of type `CPTGraphHostingView`

```
CAGradientLayer *l = [CAGradientLayer layer];
l.frame = self.hostView.bounds;
l.colors = @[ (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor ];
l.locations = @[ @0.f, @0.02f, @0.98f, @1.f ];
l.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.f, 0.5f);
l.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
self.hostView.layer.mask = l;
```